# "Keep dreaming" vs. "keep on dreaming"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Which is correct? Is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 4):

*Keep dreaming* is a staid, somewhat dry phrase. It can be used in many contexts, formal and informal. In this usage, dream can have several meanings.

I am not finished with my REM tests; please keep dreaming.

Keep dreaming, and you will never face reality.

Keep on + *ing verb* = Keep continuing/trying to + *verb.*

Keep on dreaming = Keep continuing/trying to dream.

Dream here means hope. It does not refer to having dreams while asleep.

*Keep on dreaming* is an idiomatic usage, usually used in informal language. The *on* in the phrase provides the idiomatic/informal nuance of *continuing to,* usually indicating encouragement, much as it does in [keep on trucking.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+on+trucking)

I feel like giving up on my lifelong dream, but my brother says I should keep on dreaming.

Note, *Keep on dreaming* and *keep on trucking* do not have the same meaning, but the **on** in both phrases serves the same function, namely to stress the aspect of continued trying or continued attempting to try.

We also have the phrase *keep on keeping on,* which is informal encouragement to continue battling through whatever obstacles one faces in life.

Life is so hard, but I have to keep on keeping on.

Comment: To me, *Keep dreaming, and you will never face reality.* works fine with "keep on" as well. Converse deal with *my brother says I should keep on dreaming* being used with just "keep".

Answer (score 2):

If used by themselves in a sentence, they both have the same connotation of "what you want to happen is never going to happen", in sarcastic response to a statement from somebody else that the speaker believes is unrealistic, wishful thinking. Like such:

> You think your stupid idea for a mobile app can make you the next Bill Gates? **Keep dreaming.**
>
> You think America will ever give up its power in the name of world peace? **Keep on dreaming.**

Generally I've seen the first one used more often for this connotation, but there's no appreciable difference in meaning or tone.

Comment: This is entirely a different angle of thinking. +1 for that.

Comment: It appears that somebody downvoted this answer. Mind explaining why?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of being followed by a verb (dreaming, talking, going), there is no difference in grammar or semantics between "keep" and "keep on". They both mean to continue or persevere in an action. "Continue dreaming" or "continue to dream" would both be acceptable replacements.

In casual conversation or very direct usage (a command or threat), you would hear "keep" more, since it is shorter and more to the point. For example, someone with a gun to your back might say, "Keep walking!"

The only real difference between these is when it's not a verb that follows it. "Keep quiet" is valid, for example, while "keep on quiet" is not.